# django: populating extra information of an object immediately after save

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a webservice in django that I need to serve requests as fast as I can do.
Every request updates an object. I also save request ip address for populating geographic information later.

Getting geographic information is accomplished by external service provider. I give them ip address and get geographic information.

So I want to serve user request as fast as I can and populate geographic information soon after creation/update. (after 1-2 sec)

So I need a handler, that is called 1-2 secs after responding request. And it should have the updated-or-created object as argument.

I guess it is not post_save, but I couldnt find the correct way.

Which is the best way to achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: Why do you think that the post_save signal is the wrong one?

Comment: @Jingo because Django is a synchronous framework; those signals are simply callbacks, executed when the view is being executed so before the response is sent - not afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the task is to move work out of request-response cycle. You're correct that django's signals have nothing to do with this. You may try [celery](http://celeryproject.org/) for your task, it seems to be the most mature and widely used way to move work out of request-response cycle for django.

Answer (score 1):

Like Mikhail says in his answer, a task queue, such as Celery, is definitely a good way to go.

If, for some reason, you don't want to hand off the storing of the IP to a separate task because you can't be sure the async task will have been done in time, you could at least speed up storing that info by saving it in a fast key-value store or NoSQL DB.

Redis could be a great fit. Add a call in your model's `save()` that puts the IP value in Redis, with a key that is the unique identifier for the instance of the model that called `save()`, and then add a method (or property-decorated method) called `stored_ip` or whatever that knows how to pull back the IP from Redis when you need to send it to your geo partner. When the geo stuff is done, purge the key from Redis, so that Redis doesn't run out of memory.

Saving the IP that way should be lightning-fast, without much change to your current code.